# Unable to properly load a folder with images with opencv

Tags: python, image

I have an easy task to solve. Well I thought so. It already took me 2hours now and I just can't fix the error.
Basically I just want to resize every image by a specific rate in a directory.
So path X contains lots of images and I want to resize all of them.
My approach was the following:

```py
import cv2
import glob

images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("C:\\Users\\Laptop\\Desktop\\imgs*.png")]
for file in images:
    try:
        img = cv2.imread(file)
        img_size = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.5, fy= 0.5)
        cv2.imwrite(file, img_size)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I also tried it with the os library with os.listdir()

But I always get an exception like:

`OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3784: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'`

I dont know whats wrong, either if it cant load the images properly or if I just forgot about something very important.

Maybe someone can help me...

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the exception, you should be able to view the contents of the offending `img` object, as well as which file generates the error. Unless you're getting it for all images? If not then you might just have some bad data that needs cleaning.

Comment: Im getting it for every image,..,.

Answer (score 0):

First you read in all the images:

```
images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("C:\\Users\\Laptop\\Desktop\\imgs*.png")]
```

Then for each of those images, you again call `cv2.imread`:

```
for file in images:
    img = cv2.imread(file)
```

This second `imread` makes no sense. You are passing an image array, rather than a file name to it!

You might instead want to loop like this:

```
for file in glob.glob("C:\\Users\\Laptop\\Desktop\\imgs*.png"):
  try:
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    img_size = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.5, fy= 0.5)
    cv2.imwrite(file, img_size)
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: I dont get an error anymore. However nothing happens to my exisiting files in my directory

Comment: @Dome271: Take a look at the contents of `img_size`, has it been resized? Are the files being updated? (check the creation date).

Comment: nope they are not. Literally nothing was changed by the script.

Comment: @Dome271 How about my first question? Did you look at the contents of `img_size` in one of the iterations?

Comment: However may there be an issue the way you save the file? Look, above you specify the path you want to grab every file of. But in "cv2.imwrite(file, img_size)" there is no path that points to our desired dir. Is that a problem? @Cris Luengo

Comment: How can I look at the contents? Just printing them?

Comment: @Dome271: `file` does contain the full path of the files for me (on Linux), so `imwrite` should be writing to those. You can do `print(img_size)` or `print(img_size.shape)` to see what the output of the `resize` function is. Otherwise, you might consider asking a new question? I just wanted to point out the mistake you were asking about in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after lots of trying. I figured out a way by myself.
Here is the code if someone is interested:

```py
import glob
import cv2
import os
import random



path = "C:\\Users\\Laptop\\Desktop\\imgs"
for file in os.listdir(path):
    numb = random.randint(0,1000)
    print("Test")
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, file))
    img_size = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.5, fy= 0.5)
    cv2.imwrite("C:\\Users\\Laptop\\Desktop\\imgs\\" + str(numb) + ".jpg", img_size)
```